# Undefined variable in a Component

Tags: php, laravel

My servere works in linux via apache2 but works fine on dev environment through artisan serve on Windows Machine.

The error is **Undefined variable $washProgram**

- resources/views/components/expedition-data.blade.php

```
<div>
   Programa {{ $washProgram->name }}
</div>
```

- app/View/Components/expeditionData.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class expeditionData extends Component
{

    public $op;
    public $washProgram;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($op)
    {
        $this->op = $op;
        $this->washProgram = $op->getSelectedWashProgram();
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.expedition-data');
    }
}
```

- Call to Component in Blade

```php
<x-expedition-data :op="$op" />
```

I wanted to generate a view using the component, and it gave me this error.

Comment: Odd that it works in dev but not in Apache. Do any other pages work in Apache?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? You have `washProgram` defined as a Component variable, so it should pass along to the view.

Comment: @aynber no, public fields automatically wired to component view. But seems like it's true only for component data attributes passed to constructor

Comment: I have also tried passing the attributes to the view from the render function, but the same error keeps appearing.

Comment: It might just be a caching problem. Have you tried php artisan cache:clear ?

Comment: Windows has a case-insensitive filesystem so filenames like `expeditionData.php` and `ExpeditionData.php` are interchangeable. I think Laravel will look for `ExpeditionData.php` if it sees  an `x-expedition-data` component and if it can't load it then it will use the `expedition-data.blade.php` file. Your case may be an edge case where it finds and uses the class in windows but does not find the class and uses the blade file (as an [anonymous component](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#anonymous-components)) directly in Linux. The solution (if this is the case) would be to rename your file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Linux is case-sensitive. The file names of the components are changed so that they all start with an uppercase letter:

```
expeditionData.php -> ExpeditionData.php
```